# Docker for windows: how to access container from dev machine (by ip/dns name)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Questions like seem to be asked but I really don't get it at all.

I have a window 10 dev machine host with docker for windows installed. Besides others networks it has DockerNAT netwrok with IP 10.0.75.1

I run some containers with docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
    service_a:
        build: .
        container_name: docker_a
```

It created some network `bla_default`, container has IP 172.18.0.4, ofcource I can not connect to 172.18.0.4 from host - it doesn't have any netwrok interface for this.

What should I do to be able to access this container from HOST machine? (by IP) and if possible by some DNS name? What should I add to my docker-compose.yml, how to configure netwroks?

For me it should be something basic, but I really don't understand how all this stuff works and to access to container from host directly.

Answer (score 3):

Allow access to internal docker networks from dev machine:

```
route /P add 172.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.0.75.2
```

Then use this https://github.com/aacebedo/dnsdock to enable DNS discovery.
Tips:

```
> docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name dnsdock --net bridge -p 53:53/udp aacebedo/dnsdock:latest-amd64

> add 127.0.0.1 as DNS server on dev machine

> Use labels described in docs to have pretty dns names for containers
```

So the answer on the original question: 
YES WE CAN! 
Oh, this not actual.

MAKE DOCKER GREAT AGAIN!

Comment: Thanks @whitecolor. And thanks for the workaround you supplied in the github issue. I spent far too much time on fixing access to internal containers on Windows!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is port mapping: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ports

just add

```
ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

to the service definition in compose.  If your service listens on port 80, requests to `localhost:8080` on your host will be forwarded to the container.  (I'm using docker machine, so my docker host is another IP, but I think localhost is how docker for windows appears)

Treating the service as a single process listening on one (or a few) ports has worked best for me, but if you want to start reading about networking options, here are some places to dig in:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/
Docker's official page on networking - a very high level introduction, with most of the detail on the default bridge behavior.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/concerning-containers-connections-docker-networking
More information on network layout within a docker host

http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/
Host mode is kind of mysterious, and I'm curious if it works similarly on windows.

Comment: I don't wan't to use port mapping in this case, I wan't to understand how to implement direct access to full ip surface of the container from host in immutable manner, so that I didn't need to worry about ip addresses, port numbers (to available on host), etc